# GroupPrincipal.Members.Add Sometimes Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, active-directory

For whatever reason, it just doesn't work sometimes. It's random and I can't reliably reproduce the issue. It doesn't even throw an exception, it just pretends to work but doesn't when I check at the end.

So here's the context. I'm trying to loop through one user's groups and there are 48 groups, and add these groups to another user with no groups except Domain Users. The only exception thrown is when it sees that Domain Users is already there, otherwise it keeps going.

- 100% of the time it goes through all 48 groups and tries to add them. I put a counter to be sure it was actually trying all 48 times.
- 50% of the time it only adds some of the 48. By some, I mean sometimes it adds 27, sometimes it adds 39, sometimes 38, sometimes 41, etc. I check using ADUC.
- 100% of that 50% it's random on which groups it adds or doesn't add. There isn't any one particular group it has a problem with.

My conclusion here is that something else behind the scenes is amiss. Perhaps when it saves it doesn't really save but never throws an error? Maybe active directory is broken in some way?

```
public string addUserToGroup(string strUser, string strGroup)
{
    string result = "";
    GroupPrincipal grp = GetGroupP(strGroup);
    UserPrincipal usr = GetUserP(strUser);
        try
        {
            grp.Members.Add(usr);
            grp.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.ToString();
        }

    return result;
}
```

Here is the PrincipleContext piece:

```
public PrincipalContext GetContext()
{
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, objDN, objUser, objPW);
    return ctx;
}

public UserPrincipal GetUserP(string strUser)
{
    PrincipalContext ctx = GetContext();
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, strUser);
    return user;
}

public GroupPrincipal GetGroupP(string strGroup)
{
    PrincipalContext ctx = GetContext();
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, strGroup);
    return group;
}
```

Comment: You can try using DirectoryEntry instead of GroupPrincipal. I would suggest to add all 48 groups at the same time and see what happens. Is's much more efficient from the performance point of view. I. e. pass all groups to your method, then add them and call save only once.

Comment: Hmmm, that sounds like a good idea, will need some refactoring but it could work.

Comment: This method has some limitations. If you need to add a large number of members, divide them into batches of size ~100/200

Comment: Just realized this won't work, because you have to take each group, add the user, then save it. If I could do it backwards, like take the userprinciple and add the group, it would work better. I don't think I can do that. I'm trying to add a bunch of groups to a single user, not a bunch of users to a single group.

Comment: Ok, sorry, my bad. How many domain controllers do you have in you environment?

Comment: Several. I tried specifying one that I know is good in the principalcontext and it did nothing to help. For now I've added a bandaid that basically tells it to try the whole loop again if it doesn't add up at the end.